# JQuery Date Picker with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, codeigniter, datepicker

I am using jQuery date picker in my codeigniter project

I use it like this in my view

```
  <script>
     $(function() {
       $( "#from-datepicker" ).datepicker();
     });
  </script>

  <script>
    $(function() {
      $( "#to-datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
  </script>

  <div style="float:left; width:330px">
     <input name="from-date" type="text" id="from-datepicker" />
  </div>

  <div style="float:left; width:330px">
     <input name="to-date" type="text" id="to-datepicker" />
  </div>
```

In my controller I have

```
public function titlesDownloads(){
    if($_POST){
        $form = $this->input->post();
        $boxes = $form['boxes'];
        $titles = $form['titles'];
        $from_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($form['from-date']));
        $to_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($form['to-date']));
        $data['titles_downloads'] = $this->Statistic_model->getTitlesDownloads($boxes, $titles, $ipsegments, $from_date, $to_date);
        $data['from_date'] = $from_date;
        $data['to_date'] = $to_date;
        $this->load->view('statistic/titles-downloads', $data);
    }
}
```

In my model I have the function to get the count of downloads as

```
  public function getTitlesDownloads($boxes, $titles, $from_date, $to_date){
    $query = $this->db->select('mc_boxes_idmc_boxes, mc_boxes.location, idtitle_history, titles.title, COUNT(mc_boxes_has_downloads.idtitle_history) AS Titles_Downloads ')
            ->from('mc_boxes_has_downloads')
            ->join('mc_boxes', 'mc_boxes_has_downloads.mc_boxes_idmc_boxes = mc_boxes.idmc_boxes', 'left')
            ->join('titles', 'mc_boxes_has_downloads.idtitle_history = titles.idtitles', 'left')
            ->where_in('mc_boxes_idmc_boxes', $boxes)
            ->where_in('idtitle_history', $titles)
            ->where('actiontime >=', $from_date)
            ->where('actiontime <=', $to_date)
            ->group_by('mc_boxes_idmc_boxes')
            ->group_by('idtitle_history')
            ->get();
    $data = $query->result_array();
    return $data;
}
```

Now, for a specific title id=7 there are 4 downloads in month of june. but when I run the query it returns me three. The last download which was on june 30 is skipped.

I think the date picker is skipping the upper and lower bound of the selected dates. Though in my query I wrote >= startdate and >=enddate.

Why it is skipping the lastdate ?

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since you are only passing a date and no time, it is probably assuming the time is Midnight.  So less than Midnight on Jun-30 precludes anything from Jun-30 from being displayed.

Your best bet might be to just add a day and use less than to find anything that occurred the day before.

Comment: how can I pass the time as well ?

Comment: Is the user selecting the time in the datepicker?  Based on how you are setting up the datepicker it doesn't appear that way.  So you either modify it before the form is submitted or handle it when you process the post.